# Rearranging array data into table

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script to get some values from a large CSV file.

Below is some sample data. I use a script attached to group the data by ID1 and ID2 (those ID's are the same, but i need both of them), Service and sum values.

I get output like that:

[image]

But I'd like an output like an Excel table - with ID1 and Id2 in left columns, Services in upper row and sum of each ID, Service in the table bellow. Something like that:

[image]

I'd like to export that to CSV so I can open it in Excel. Can it be done? How?

```
$data = @(
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;Service='Service1';Propertyx=1;Price='5'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;Service='Service2';Propertyx=1;Price='4'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;Service='Service4';Propertyx=2;Price='4'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;Service='Service4';Propertyx=2;Price='1'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;Service='Service2';Propertyx=2;Price='3'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;Service='Service1';Propertyx=1;Price='17'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;Service='Service2';Propertyx=1;Price='13'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;Service='Service3';Propertyx=1;Price='7'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;Service='Service1';Propertyx=1;Price='2'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;Service='Service1';Propertyx=1;Price='3'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;Service='Service2';Propertyx=1;Price='11'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;Service='Service1';Propertyx=1;Price='7'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;Service='Service3';Propertyx=1;Price='5'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;Service='Service2';Propertyx=1;Price='4'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;Service='Service2';Propertyx=1;Price='12'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;Service='Service3';Propertyx=1;Price='8'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;Service='Service1';Propertyx=1;Price='7'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;Service='Service5';Propertyx=1;Price='7'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;Service='Service3';Propertyx=1;Price='7'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;Service='Service1';Propertyx=1;Price='3'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;Service='Service2';Propertyx=1;Price='11'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;Service='Service1';Propertyx=1;Price='7'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;Service='Service3';Propertyx=1;Price='5'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;Service='Service2';Propertyx=1;Price='4'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;Service='Service4';Propertyx=1;Price='12'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;Service='Service5';Propertyx=1;Price='8'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;Service='Service1';Propertyx=1;Price='7'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;Service='Service5';Propertyx=1;Price='7'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='5';Id2=53252352;Service='Service1';Propertyx=1;Price='7'})


   $Grouping = $data | group Id1, Id2, Service
   $grouping| foreach {
    $b= $_.name -split ', '
    [pscustomobject] @{
         Id1 = $b[0]; Id2 = $b[1];Service = $b[2]
        'Sum Value' = ($_.group | measure Price -sum).sum
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're looking is usually known as a "pivot". There's AFAIK nothing like that built into PowerShell, but you can code your own, look at GitHub for library code, or e.g. let Excel do the lifting for you. https://www.powershellbros.com/create-pivot-table-in-excel-powershell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start with your `$data` object creation, you may do the following:

```
# Determine new columns based on unique Service values
$newcols = ('Id1','Id2')+($data | Select -Expand Service -Unique | Sort)

# Initially group on Id1,Id2
$data | group Id1,Id2 | Foreach-Object {
    # Create new object with required columns
    # Use index [0] since currently all objects have the same data for the new columns
    $obj = $_.Group[0] | Select $newcols
    # Grouping on Service
    $_.Group | group Service | Foreach-Object {
        # Extracting Service name
        $service = $_.Group[0].Service
        # Summing Price for target Service
        $sum = ($_.Group.Price | Measure -Sum).Sum
        # Update target Service name property on new object
        $obj.$service = $sum 
    }
    # Output new object when all Service names have been processed
    $obj
}
```

Output if you pipe the code to Format-Table:

```
Id1      Id2 Service1 Service2 Service3 Service4 Service5
---      --- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
1   51213412        5        7        8        5        8
2   11112314       19       35       17
3   12512521        6        8                12       14
4   42112521       28       12        7
5   53252352        7
```